# A simply connected region $D$ that contains the boundary of $S$ contains $S$

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis, algebraic-topology

> If $D\subseteq X$ is a simply connected subspace of the topological space $X$ and [add assumptions here] and $S\subseteq X$, $\partial(S)\subseteq D$, then $S\subseteq D$.

It doesn't seem to be true for higher dimensions, i.e. $S^2=\partial(B^3)$ is simply connected but does not contain $B^3$, the closed unit sphere. But for subsets of $\Bbb C$ (or equivalently $\Bbb R^2$), this seems to be some sort of corollary of the fundamental group of the circle. (The boundary may need to be the path of some continuous function $\gamma$, I'm not sure if this is necessary.) It also has a sort of 2D intermediate value theorem feel to it, and I wonder if there is a way to prove it that way. I'm still looking at approaches to prove $\pi_1(S^1, x)\simeq\Bbb Z$, and I'm not sure which result more easily applies the other.

Note: Although I'm still trying to get the correct form for this theorem, the original source which made me expect a result of this type was this [proof of the Cauchy-Goursat theorem](http://serge.mehl.free.fr/pdf/CauchyGoursatTheorem.pdf). Specifically, they have a simply connected region $D\subseteq\Bbb C$ with $C\subseteq D$ a triangular contour, and they set $T_0$ to be the interior of the region, and construct a sequence of subsets $T_n\supseteq T_{n+1}$ with diameters going to $0$, so that the intersection is a point $z\in T$, which they claim is also in $D$ "because $D$ is simply connected".

Comment: What is a region?

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something fundamental, but is $D=B^2$ (unit disc) and $S=\overline{\mathbb{C}\setminus B^2}$ not a counter-example? Moreover, what is $\partial S$ in general (unless you fixed some ambient space such as $\mathbb{C}$)?

Comment: @PeterFranek Yes, the concepts only make sense with respect to an ambient space, such as $\Bbb C$; $S$ and $\partial S$ are computed relative to this space. Your example of $S=\Bbb C\setminus B^2$ is a good one; it's not obvious why any null homotopy of $\partial S$ would cover the "interior" and not the "exterior" region, and this is in fact false on $S^2$ (unit sphere), which can close its loops in two different directions. So I guess this is a property unique to $\Bbb C$ and not shared by other topological spaces.

Comment: @PeterFranek I realize that my claim has a lot of holes; I hope a good answer to state the assumptions needed to make it true. I'm fairly certain it is true on $\Bbb C$ if $\partial(S)=\gamma$ is a continuous closed path and $S$ is bounded (i.e. the interior not exterior region).